# Type of object destructuring including arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript, destructuring

I'd like to destrucure an object using Typescript where part of the object is an Array. Here is an example:

```
const myObj = {"fruits": ["apples", "oranges"]};
Object.entries(myObj).forEach((item) => {
    const [headline, fruitsArr] = item;
    fruitsArr.forEach((fruit) => console.log(fruit));
})
```

The error I get is that fruitsArr is of Type 'unknown'. So I guess I have to assign types to the line where I define [headline, fruitsArr] but I don't know how. Any help, please?

Comment: according to [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeAiAMwCcBXASygjwC4YBtPAQwAdmAbAUyoBoY8QijMAHMueALoBfANwAoVGg7AoAOg5goRMlwAUiBQEoVBAQFFGwABY6dFDnANYAfLlkx3MUJFh1LHRgAmbGRgHLzE5JQAgkRE4lgwdnByHjARFBAxRMZmFtY66VCOmC5eECCcKmwgwgWkFAYGcpIGQA) the code you posted should be typed correctly (`fruitsArr` is `string[]`)

Comment: Where are you seeing that error?

Comment: Hm. I see that error in my VS Code. The fruitsArr.forEach is underlined red and I see the error when I mouse over it. Ok, my real code is a little more complicated of course. This was only an example above.

Comment: You need to sjow where you get the `myObj`  from.